# pretty printing in haskell with data structure

Tags: haskell

I am the beginner of Haskell, and I want to make a pretty printing with data structures in Haskell.

I have the following data structure:

https://codeshare.io/5zl9WD

I want to print the following value:

```
int a(int b, int* c){
   return b + *c;
}
```

by using the following function types:

```
pFunc :: f -> document

putStrLn $ pretty 40 $ pFunc fun

fun =("a", TInt, [(TInt, "b"),(TPtr TInt, "c")]
      , [SReturn (EBinOp "+" (EIdent "b") (EUnOpPre "*" (EIdent "c")))])
```

`document` data structure is as the following:

https://codeshare.io/G64gyg

But honestly I don't have any idea. I have many similar simple printings. If I can have an idea about this printing, the remaining one won't be a problem.

But might be the shortest way to print the value above by using `document` data type?

Comment: Please add the relevant definitions in those links to the question.

Comment: What is this for? Is it homework?

Comment: It is just a very small part of a homework. Not the whole one.

Comment: @yusuf What have you tried then?

Comment: Honestly, my brain stopped working at this task. I need a small fire for start :) Forgive me

Comment: Your types must start with upper-case characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a pretty-printer function for each of the types in the abstract-syntax-tree.  Each function will have type:

```
pretty<Foo> :: <Foo> -> Document
```

where you replace `<Foo>` with the type name.  Work bottom up, so you can test each function as you write it.  i.e. implement the pretty-printer for `Type` first, since it is needed by the pretty-printer for `Stmt` and `f` (which should be called `Func` or something).

For instance:

```
prettyType :: Type -> Document
prettyType TVoid     = text "void"
prettyType TInt      = text "int"
prettyType TFloat    = text "float"
prettyType TChar     = text "char"
prettyType TPtr t    = prettyType t <> text "*"
prettyType TStruct s = text "struct" <+> text s
```

Follow the same pattern for each of `Exp`, `Stmt`, `Case`, and `Func`.

Comment: Hi @pat, I did. what might be next? :)

Comment: Write a `main` function `main = putStrLn $ pretty 40 $ pFunc fun` where `pFunc` is the pretty printer you wrote for functions.  Then run it...